# Materialize select set dynamic options issue

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I have two dependent dropdowns (Materialize select) country and state.On selecting country i'm getting respected states using javascript, and i'm adding options to state select but its showing empty in state dropdown...but when i put alert, the values comes correctly. Can anyone help me to sort this issue ?

Edit:
using inspect after removing display:none for select i'm getting like below..actual html select dropdown gets populated correctly but materialize select not showing or getting populated why ?
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLc02.jpg) 
HTML CODE:

```
 <select name="country" id="country" onchange="setStates();" style="width:100px; font-weight:bold;" >
     <option value="">Select</option>
      /* Country  options here */
    </select>
 <select name="state" id="state" style="width:100px; font-weight:bold;" >
    </select>
```

Javascript code:

```
function setStates() {

  cntrySel = document.getElementById('country');
  stateList = states[cntrySel.value];

  changeSelect('state', stateList, stateList);
}

function changeSelect(fieldID, newOptions, newValues) {
  selectField = document.getElementById(fieldID);
  selectField.options.length = 0;

  for (i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
    selectField.options[selectField.length] = new Option(newOptions[i], newValues[i]);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-initialize materialize select, try this:

```
function setStates() {

  cntrySel = document.getElementById('country');
  stateList = states[cntrySel.value];

  changeSelect('state', stateList, stateList);
}

function changeSelect(fieldID, newOptions, newValues) {
  selectField = document.getElementById(fieldID);
  selectField.options.length = 0;

  for (i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
    selectField.options[selectField.length] = new Option(newOptions[i], newValues[i]);
  }
  // Materialize old version
  $('#'+fieldID).material_select();
  // Materialize new version
  $('#'+fieldID).select();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function setStates() {

  cntrySel = document.getElementById('country');
  stateList = states[cntrySel.value];

  changeSelect('state', stateList, stateList);
}

function changeSelect(fieldID, newOptions, newValues) {
  selectField = document.getElementById(fieldID);
  selectField.options.length = 0;

  for (i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
    selectField.innerHTML= "<option value=\"" + newValue[i] + "\">" + newOption[i] + "</option>"
  }

}
```

Comment: sorry not working either...still got empty dropdown..please check my question edit

Comment: please check image,in materialize select only not gets populated, but actual html select working correctly

Comment: this is the complete code, two dropdowns and javascript two populate that